# NSPopover color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopover

Is there any way to color NSPopover? Ive seen apps like facetab etc that have cool colors and resizeable popovers, how is this done?

Ay guides, hints?

Thanks.

Comment: For the record: the color of the "frame" (the arrow and a thin border) is something like `[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.980 green:0.955 blue:0.956 alpha:1.000]` — I "grabbed" this thanks to http://panic.com/~wade/picker

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978620/how-to-change-nspopover-background-color-include-triangle-part, where there is an interesting option to use the native NSPopover + private API to access the view used to draw the triangle (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29862351/9900)

Comment: Please give this solution a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978620/how-to-change-nspopover-background-color-include-triangle-part/30660945#30660945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/source/index.html#maattachedwindow) instead.

Comment: I used this solution for a while and ended up writing my own NSWindow subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Set `popover.contentViewController.view` as a subclass of `NSView` with a custom background drawing (i.e. override `drawRect:` and fill a rect with your custom background color).

Then set the `popover.appearance = NSPopoverAppearanceHUD` to remove the default border around the view.

Note that there will still be a very thin border around the view, so if you want to remove it completely, you may want to use [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/source/index.html#maattachedwindow) or a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4:

1. Go to File->New File->Cocoa Class
2. Name your class. eg. PopColor. Make sure it is a subclass of NSView
3. Set the contents of the file to:

```
import Cocoa

class PopoverContentView:NSView {
    var backgroundView:PopoverBackgroundView?
    override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        if let frameView = self.window?.contentView?.superview {
            if backgroundView == nil {
                backgroundView = PopoverBackgroundView(frame: frameView.bounds)
                backgroundView!.autoresizingMask = NSView.AutoresizingMask([.width, .height]);
                frameView.addSubview(backgroundView!, positioned: NSWindow.OrderingMode.below, relativeTo: frameView)
            }
        }
    }
}

class PopoverBackgroundView:NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.green.set()
        self.bounds.fill()
    }
}
```

4. In your storyboard, select the view which has your popover content and go to the Identity Inspector
5. Set the Class to PopoverContentView

Your popover and its triangle will now be green.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `NSView` and set it as the `NSPopover`'s view controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Unfortunately `NSPopover` isn't designed to be customisable. You can use some simple hacks for adding additional background view behind `contentViewController`'s `view` and colorise or customise it as you want. In this case, you can get the customisable background that will be masked the same as generic `NSPopover` border and tail.

For more details you can take a look at the code of [`NSPopover+MISSINGBackgroundView`](https://github.com/shergin/NSPopover-MISSINGBackgroundView/blob/master/Pod/Classes/NSPopover%2BMISSINGBackgroundView.m) category that implements this approach or just use this piece of code as CocoaPod library.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code to change the color of NSPopover including the triangle is here:

*I assume people have hooked the popover outlets and methods*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MyPopoverBackgroundView : NSView
@end


@implementation MyPopoverBackgroundView

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill(self.bounds);
}

@end

//===============================================================================================
@interface MyPopView : NSView
@end

@implementation MyPopView
-(void)viewDidMoveToWindow{
    NSView *aFrameView = [[self.window contentView] superview];
    MyPopoverBackgroundView * aBGView  =[[MyPopoverBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrameView.bounds];
    aBGView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
    [aFrameView addSubview:aBGView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:aFrameView];
    [super viewDidMoveToWindow];
}
@end



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    //close when clicked outside
    [self.popover setBehavior:NSPopoverBehaviorTransient];


    //change its color
    MyPopView *myPopview = [MyPopView new];
    [self.popover.contentViewController.view addSubview:myPopview];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


- (IBAction)closePopover:(id)sender {
    [self.popover close];
}

- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender {

    [self.popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds]
                              ofView:sender
                       preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}


@end
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more info for beginners on how to implement this? Cheers!

Comment: @Ribena: I have added all the code - you need to copy-paste and change only the class name as `MyPopoverBackgroundView`, or create a class with this same name. And create popup and hook it in your xib. Or if you've some specific concern please let me know.

Answer (score -4):

This is what I did to change the popover color.

Assuming that you have properly defined your NSPopover:

```
//AppController.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopover errorPopover;
// whatever else you have ...
@end

//AppController.m
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController
@synthesize errorPopover = _errorPopover;
// whatever else you have ...

-(IBAction)doSomethingThatCallsPopover:(id)sender {
_errorPopover.appearance = NSPopoverAppearanceHUD; //set color of error popup
[[self errorPopover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
}
@end
```

[NSPopover Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010720) - I really wish they would provide usage code in the developer docs.

Comment: This just uses the HUD style (which is a dark color) but it does not let you set any color you want